# Как программно нажать на кнопку в tkinter (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

Как *программно* нажать на кнопку в **tkinter**? (**Python**)

Comment: Button.invoke()

Comment: Кнопки специально делают, чтобы на них нажимали _не программно_.  С чем связана ваша задача изманить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ткинтере нажатие кнопки вызывает функцию.
`button.config(command=fun1)`можно сразу её вызвать в нужный момент, и какбы вы нажали эту кнопку.`fun1()`